Richik gotra — Kanyakubj brahmin
What does it mean when my grandfather tells the pandit that we are of Richik gotra at the temple? The pandit seems to understand, but I can’t find any information about this gotra. I am aware of who Richik is, I just didn’t know there was a gotra named after him.
My family is one of Kanyakubj/Saryuparin Brahmins from Purvanchal in case this is useful context.
